# Question about namespace

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are unnamed namespaces used and what are their benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits)

```
namespace {

// EINTR sucks.
int close_no_eintr(int fd) {
  int result;
  do {
    result = close(fd);
  } while (result < 0 && errno == EINTR);
  return result;
}
```

In the code above, why there is not a name after namespace in the first line?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are unnamed namespaces used and what are their benefits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/anonymous-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

It is an [unnamed namespace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/unnamed_namespaces.htm). It prevents names from leaking out of the current file, which they would do if declared as globals.

Comment: "Items defined in an unnamed namespace have internal linkage. Rather than using the keyword static to define items with internal linkage, define them in an unnamed namespace instead. " what is its meaning by "internal linkage" ?

Comment: @Jinx Linking internal to the file.  As opposed to external linkage, which is linking to something in a different file.  Look at the excellent answer to the question that this question was marked a dup of.