# Should I always give my global functions internal linkage?

Tags: c++, linkage

I have a TU whose global functions won't be used by any other TUs. I read that declaring them as `static` gives them internal linkage, and this is good from an optimization standpoint. But I want to know what are the correct situations in which I should use them. Should I *always* give global functions/variables internal linkage when I know they won't be used anywhere else in the program?

Comment: "and this is good from an optimization standpoint" no.

Comment: It's possible that your choice of what to do here will affect compile times, but it will be transparent at run time.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It doesn't help the compiler optimize?

Comment: If they are not `static` and not in an unnamed namespace, then you risk a name clash with another TU doing the same thing, which will silently cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put them in an [unnamed namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) instead.

This is the [idiomatic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312213/uses-of-unnamed-namespace-in-c) in C++ for functions that will be used only in the current TU.