# g++ says references are undefined even though `nm` lists the symbol definitions in my object files

Tags: c++, linker, g++

When the Makefile for a project I'm working on hits this line:

```
g++ -g build_complex.o simplex.o simplex_src.o split.o permutation_src.o permutation_parity.o tropmod.o main.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/ -ligraph -lm -o cpptest
```

I get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
/home/xander/Desktop/tropicalmoduli/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::ConfigSpace::ConfigSpace(int, int)'
/home/xander/Desktop/tropicalmoduli/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::PermWrapper::PermWrapper(permutation*)'
/home/xander/Desktop/tropicalmoduli/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `(anonymous namespace)::ConfigSpace::getTraceOfPerm((anonymous namespace)::PermWrapper)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Those are functions that are defined in the file tropmod.cpp, which was compiled to tropmod.o. When I run `nm tropmod.o` spits out:

```
                 U __cxa_atexit
                 U __dso_handle
                 U free
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
000000000000037c t _GLOBAL__sub_I_tropmod.cpp
                 U igraph_destroy
                 U malloc
                 U _Z10split_freeP5split
                 U _Z12simplex_freeP7simplex
                 U _Z13simplex_traceP7simplexP11permutation
                 U _Z14get_1_skeletoniiPPP5split
                 U _Z16get_mid_skeletoniiiPiPP5splitP8igraph_s
0000000000000333 t _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
00000000000001f0 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111ConfigSpace14getTraceOfPermENS_11PermWrapperE
000000000000010c t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111ConfigSpace7destroyEv
0000000000000000 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111ConfigSpaceC2Eii
0000000000000322 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111PermWrapper14getPermutationEv
0000000000000304 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111PermWrapperC2EP11permutation
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
                 U _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
0000000000000000 b _ZStL8__ioinit
```

All the "undefined references" are listed here, with a "t", which should mean that they're defined in this object file. Both tropmod.o and main.o were compiled from .cpp files which include the header file `tropmod.hpp`, where the declarations can be found:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "build_complex.h"

#ifdef tmboost
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
typedef boost::python::list bplist;
#endif

namespace {

    // allows a permutation to be converted from python::boost::list
    // to permutation* just once, and then reused
    class PermWrapper {
        permutation *perm;

        public:
        #ifdef tmboost 
        PermWrapper(bplist);
        #endif
        PermWrapper(permutation*);

        permutation *getPermutation();
    };

    class ConfigSpace {
        int n,d;
        int *num_cells;
        int num_facets;
        split **all_splits;
        simplex ***skels;

        public:
        ConfigSpace(int n, int d);

        void destroy();

        int getTraceOfPerm(PermWrapper perm);
    };
}
```

For completeness, here is `main.cpp`:

```
#include "tropmod.hpp"

int main() {

    ConfigSpace cs = ConfigSpace(2, 2);

    int p_d[4] = {1, 0, 3, 2};
    permutation *p = perm_alloc_data(4, p_d);
    PermWrapper pw = PermWrapper(p);

    printf("trace: %i\n", cs.getTraceOfPerm(pw));
}
```

Both cpp files were compiled with `g++ -g -fPIC -c` (and without the `tmboost` flag).

I looked at several other questions on here concerning this kind of linking error, but none of the answers I read are obviously applicable here. It seems like all the pieces are there, does anyone have an idea why the linker can't put it together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, [anonymous namespaces are local to their translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits), and they cannot be referenced from other translation units.

If you read `nm`'s documentation, it clearly states that lowercase letters specify local symbol types.

If these were global symbols, they would be marked as "T", and not "t".

Comment: That was exactly it - thanks very much. I did know that 't' meant local, but I thought that local in that context referred to a shared library, rather than the individual object file.