# c++ use class or not for permutation algorithm

Tags: c++, class, styles

I have written a program, which takes an input `vector` of integers and prints all possible permutations of these integers.

In order to do that my program has two methods:
`void Permutate(//input)` and `void DoPermute(//necessary arguments)`
Only the method `Permutate` should be called by the user/client. `DoPermutate` is a recursive method which is firstly called by `Permutate` and provides the logic for the algorithm.
The question now: would you put `Permutate` and `DoPermutate` in a `class` and make `DoPermutate` `private`, or would you put both methods in the global scope and not use `classes` at all and thus expose `DoPermutate` to the user/client? I am asking this because `cmath` also has the utility methods in a global scope.
What would be a more elegant approach?

Comment: I assume this is for a school assignment or similar? Because otherwise you could just use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: You do know that [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) already exists, right?

Comment: General rule of thumb is If the function doesn't require any state information that isn't provided as a parameter, don't put it in a class.

Comment: I am asking this mostly for education purposes. This concept of algorithms that use helper methods can be applied for a variety of problems, e.g Mergesort and Quicksort. I am mostly curious about which style is more elegant when dealing with these 2 method algorithms: Use a class and hide logic or not using classes and expose the helper method.

Comment: @user4581301 Sometimes a class is a useful organizational structure for encapsulating an algorithm if you're using a design pattern that requires passing these around. Normally you'd write a sort algorithm as a straight-up function, but if you take a different approach you could pass around an instance of an object derived from an abstract base which defines the operations it can perform. Not always a clear-cut line here. These classes tend to be super tiny, often little more than a pointer, which makes them pretty cost-effective.

Comment: If you want to hide `DoPermutate` consider using an [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits)

Answer (score 1):

> The question now: would you put `Permutate` and `DoPermutate` in a class

This is what I would to:

1. Declare `Permutate` in a `namespace`, such as:

   ```
   namespace MyApp
   {
      // Declare
      void Permutate( ... ); // Add all the necessary arguments,
                             // which can be input arguments ad
                             // output arguments.
   }
   ```

   Please note that the declaration does not expose whether a class is used in the implementation. That is detail of the implementation that does not need to be exposed in the interface.
2. If it is helpful to use a class in the implementation, use it.

   ```
   namespace MyApp
   {
      // Helper class
      struct PermutateClass { ... };

      // Implement the user facing function.
      void Permutate ( ... )
      {
         // Delegate the implementation to the helper class.
         PermuateClass p(...);
         p.doIt();
      }
   }
   ```
3. If it is not helpful to use a class, just use helper functions as needed.

   ```
   namespace MyApp
   {
      // Helper function
      void DoPermutate ( ... ) { ... }

      // Implement the user facing function.
      void Permutate ( ... )
      {
         // Delegate the implementation to the helper function.
         DoPermutate p(...);
      }
   }
   ```

The key point I want to emphasize is that whether you use a helper class with a bunch of member functions or a bunch of non-member function is an implementation detail that you should be able choose without impacting the users of the user facing function.