# Unnamed namespace or Named namespace or Inlining

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline

**Headers:**

This [tutorial](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL59-CPP.+Do+not+define+an+unnamed+namespace+in+a+header+file) explains why not to use `unnamed namespaces` in headers.

That's why we get two options to declare non-member functions in headers: `Named namespace` vs `Inline functions`.

Explain please:

When do you use each?

What's the right way to use them?

- If `Named namespace` then declaration in header and definition in cpp?
- If `Inline` then declaration + definition in the header?

**Cpp:**

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits) that using `unnamed namespace` is useful only in cpp and it can help to make names internal in the translation unit and avoid name collisions.

If there are any cases to use `named namespaces` or `inline functions` in cpp?

Comment: There is no `VS` inbetween `Named namespace` and `Inline functions`.

Comment: @VTT change to "or"

Comment: This writeup is fubar.

Comment: My point is that `named namespaces` and `inline functions` are separate, unrelated concepts that should not be threated as alternatives. Also I must mention that that tutorial is rather misleading in several ways and their suggestion to not define an unnamed namespace in a header file (and "compliant " examples) are conceptually wrong. Spawning separate entities in each translation unit could be a desired behavior while spreading `extern` globals is typically not a good idea.

Comment: Just spotted your links. You should make them stand out better. We of the bad colour vision easily miss one-word links.

Comment: It looks like you want the difference between anonymous namespaces and inline namespaces, not inline functions.

Comment: @VTT And what are the correct suggestions?