# Placing a namespace-scope file-local (.cpp) constant in an anonymous namespace or not

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, c++03, linkage

A (file-local; .cpp) const-qualified variable declared at namespace-scope has internal linkage and is thus translation unit local. Is there any reason to/effect of still wrapping the constant in an anonymous namespace?

E.g., is there any reason to prefer any of the following two over the other, and if so, why?

```
// file.cpp
namespace foo {

const int kMyLocalConstant = 42;  // internal linkage

}  // namespace foo
```

vs

```
// file.cpp
namespace foo {
namespace {

const int kMyLocalConstant = 42;  // internal linkage

}  // namespace
}  // namespace foo
```

I'm grateful to get answers for C++03 as well as C++11, if there is any different in-between the two for this context.

---

**Possible duplicates**

I have read the excellent answer to

- [Why are unnamed namespaces used and what are their benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits)

but I don't see it answering my specific question (please correct me if I'm wrong), as the answer focuses on non-const variable identifiers and non-static free functions. My question focuses on file-local namespace-scoped constants, i.e., variable identifiers which already have internal linkage. Maybe there is a more appropriate dupe that I haven't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strongly prefer unnamed namespace.

Why? Because it makes the rule very easy to remember: if I'm creating a variable/function/template that is intended to be local to a translation unit, I put it in an unnamed namespace, unconditionally, and then I don't have to worry about anything again.

It's true that [a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have external linkage](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3.2) will also have internal linkage, but are you really going to choose to put your non-const variables in an unnamed namespace, but const ones outside of one? This would be error-prone if you accidentally forget the `const`:

```
// some_tu.cpp
namespace foo {
    int oops = 42;
}
```

And would you ever mix and match? That's weird:

```
// some_other_tu.cpp
namespace foo {
    const int a = 0;
    namespace {
        int b;
    }
}
```

Unnamed namespaces are free - the only cost is the characters it takes to type it. And it means nobody has to stare at this code and have to recall all the subtlety around the [basic.link] rules.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Barry. I guess apart from `inline` variables (C++17?), essentially the same quite exhaustive [basic.link] rule also holds for C++03 and C++11? I.e., it was never a trivial exercise to decide the linkage of a namespace scope variable.

Comment: @dfri Yeah, [C++11 wording](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.link#3.2). Added wording about `volatile` at some point too.

Comment: Is there any risk of collision with names from 3rd-party code `#include`d in this translation unit? If so, is there some small value to confining all project code to the project's namespace?

Comment: @JohnMcFarlane I mean, if you get an ambiguous lookup, you can always change something - but is that really a big deal? Do you have a lot of includes that define names in the global namespace that happen to match whatever names you wanted to use for some local variable?

Answer (score 1):

The unnamed namespace is redundant, there is no benefit using it in this case.

The only case I'd put a `const` into an unnamed namespace is when there's other stuff (functions, etc.), which should have internal linkage too, and the `const` and the other stuff are coherent.