# Function in source file already defined in another source file error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header, linker

```cpp
// file1.h
#pragma once
void public1();
```

```cpp
// file1.cpp
#include "file1.h"
void privateFunc() {}
void public1() {}
```

```cpp
// file2.h
#pragma once
void public2();
```

```cpp
// file2.cpp
#include "file2.h"
void privateFunc() {}
void public2() {}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

So I have 2 functions in the 2 implementation files that have the same name and same parameters, but the implementation is different. Both are not included in their header file, so I assume they compiler can distinguish them. I think this is the problem.

How can I make function `privateFunc()` private to the implementation file without putting it in a class? That is, when another file includes "file1.h" or "file2.h", it should not know `privateFunc()` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a function private, you must declare it as `static`.  Otherwise that symbol will be made available to the linker for resolving across multiple sources.

```
static void privateFunc() {}
```

Alternatively, you can declare it in an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace
{
    void privateFunc() {}
}
```

You can read more about unnamed namespaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357404/1553090).

Comment: Ah I didn't know that specific meaning of static exists. "static" in this situation means "do not include into other file", is it correct?

Comment: It means the function has internal linkage.  This means another object file cannot reference it.  Read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration