# Is it good C++ to define classes in .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I have a question regarding C++ design.

My file contains `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E` class definitions. Class `A` contains the API which is used by other applications. I have defined this in a `.h` file. Classes `B`,`C`,`D` & `E` define concrete classes by inheriting an abstract class which is provided by some library. These definitions are not used by any external application, but only used by class `A`.

I have seen online that all the class definitions are provided in an `.h` file and the function implementations in a `.cpp` file. My question here is, even though class `B`,`C`,`D` & `E` definitions are not used externally by anyone, should I define them in the `.h` file? If I do define them there anyway, I cannot expose them to other applications, right?

Comment: No, you define them in .cpp if you can.

Comment: You can declare a class in a Cpp file. You cannot use such class outside of that file.

Comment: I echo HolyBlackCat. Don't expose something you don't need to be part of the API. Oh, and wrap those classes in an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces), so that everything gets proper internal linkage.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You mean class A,B,C,D,E should be wrapped in an unnamed namespace or just class B,C,D,E

Comment: Not A. Just the others

Answer (score 3):

If a class is only used locally in one module, you can declare it in the .cpp file.  This is actually good practice; don't expose more than necessary.

In a case where you need to define a class (or function, etc.) in a header (for example, to share it between several related .cpp file) but you do not want to expose it publicly, you can have a separate, private header file which is only included in the relevant places, but is not made public.  This can be hinted at by appending "private" to the header file name.

Comment: Another techniques to hide implementation details (even from the linker) is to use [anonymous / unnamed namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits) (better than "private header"). May be worth mentioning to improve your answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- if I understand correctly, anonymous namespaces will limit access to one translation unit -- how does that replace the private header, which limits use to several, related, translation units?

Comment: Seems I didn't read properly that you proposed more than one unit. In that case anonymous namespaces won't help. You're right about that.