# c++ overload operator inside a class for another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a class A, and I define an overload of an operator, acting on a class of the standard library.
To have a concrete example, see following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs) {
   if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
        throw(std::runtime_error("incompatible vectors"));
   std::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), lhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return x + y; });
   return lhs;
}

template <typename T>
struct A {
   std::vector<T> v;
   A(const T& x) : v(3, x) { }
   void add (const std::vector<T>& rhs) { v += rhs; }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(1);
    std::vector<int> bvec(3, 2);
    a.add(bvec);

    return 0;
}
```

Check it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2b267e42cb87108).

The code works as expected. However, I would like to "hide" the overload of `operator+=`, such that it can be only used by `struct A`.

The reason is that, since `operator +=` is a template one, I would need to insert it into a header, to be included whenever I need `struct A` in a compilation unit: this could potentially generates conflicts, for example if the compilation unit already has defined an `operator+=` for `std::vector`.

One way to "hide" it could be wrap everything inside a `namespace`:

```
namespace code {
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs) {

// ....

template <typename T>
struct A {

// ....
}
```

This seems a bit cumbersome, and again, if the code contains `using namespace code`, which I cannot prevent, it could still generate conflicts. Moreover, every other routines inserted inside the `namespace code` will be able to access to `operator+=`, again with potential conflicts.

Another solution could be to hide the operation inside the definition of `struct A`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct A {
private:
   template <typename U>
   void do_add(const std::vector<U>& rhs) {
   if (v.size() != rhs.size())
        throw(std::runtime_error("incompatible vectors"));
   std::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), v.begin(), v.begin(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return x + y; });
}
public:
   std::vector<T> v;
   A(const T& x) : v(3, x) { }
   void add (const std::vector<T>& rhs) { do_add(rhs); }
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a(1);
    std::vector<int> bvec(3, 2);
    a.add(bvec);

    return 0;
}
```

(Obviously I could directly implement everything inside `A::add`, the above code is for illustration only-- in a real case several methods of `A` may need to call `do_all`, hence a separate private implementation).

The drawback of this solution is that it "ruins" a bit the readability of the code: now I have to call a routine `do_add` for doing something which is "logically" an `operator+=`.

Ideally, I would prefer to write something like

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
private:
    std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs);
// ...
}
```

that is, defining an `operator+=` inside the private part of `struct A`. In this way I would use the clear syntax `v += rhs`, and still restrict the use of `operator+=` to the code inside `struct A`.
Alas, the code above cannot compile, because the compiler expects that `operator+=` inside `struct A` deals with objects of type `A`...

If the member `v` would be a user-defined type `X`, then I could indeed insert `operator+=` in the definition of `X`. But again, not for std classes. And, deriving from the std is UB.

Then, a third solution would be to wrap `std::vector` inside a custom class

```
template <typename T>
class vec_wrapper {
   vec_wrapper<T>& operator+=(const vec_wrapper& rhs);
   std::vector<T>& m_data;
   //...
}
```

But this is extremly cumbersome: If I then want to use my `vec_wrapper` as usual `std::vector` I would need to provide a duplicate of all `std::vector` member functions, say `T& operator[](std::size_t n) { return m_data[n]; }`, etc...

So, the question is: is there a way to mantain the "nicely" defined overload of `operator+=`, but restrict its use to `struct A`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits

Comment: Sometimes shortening the code just isn't worth it. Adding `static std::vector<T>& increment(std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs)` to use instead of the operator may even make the code simpler to understand...

Answer (score 0):

You may inspire by [std::string operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) and define the member operator.

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
   std::vector<T> v;
   A(const T& x) : v(3, x) { }
   void add (const std::vector<T>& rhs) { (*this) += rhs; }
   
    A<T>& operator+=(const std::vector<T>& rhs) {
       if (v.size() != rhs.size())
            throw(std::runtime_error("incompatible vectors"));
       std::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), v.begin(), v.begin(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return x + y; });
       return *this;
    }
};
```

usage:

```
int main()
{
    A<int> a(1);
    std::vector<int> bvec(3, 2);
    a.add(bvec);
    
    a += std::vector<int>(3, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**:
If you want to preserve the operator in the way you declared it and just make it visible to the A class then just move the operator to A.cpp file and mark it as `static`. Static function is only visible in its object file.

```
// Visible only for this compilation unit (A.cpp)
template <typename T>
static std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, const std::vector<T>& rhs) 
{
   if (lhs.size() != rhs.size())
        throw(std::runtime_error("incompatible vectors"));
   std::transform(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), lhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y) { return x + y; });
   return lhs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in an actual code I could more than 1 vector, and not necessarily a member field (it could be, say, a local variable)...

Comment: I mean that, for example, the class may hold ```std::vector<double> v1, v2```, and in a routine you want to do sometimes ```v1 += v```, or ```v2 += v```, or even ```v1 += v2```. Or inside a member function, you have perhaps a local ```std::vector v_local```, and you want to do ```v_local += v```. I think your solution is not flexible enough to treat all cases...

Comment: @francesco That was my solution, not his. Also, you did not include those cases in your sample code and question. I edited the answer. I hope it solves your issue.